# python converting hexadecimal binary to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex

I am using `python3.5` and I wish to write output I get in hexadecimal bytes (`b'\x00'`, `b'\x01'` etc) to python strings with `\x00 -> 0`  and `\x01 -> 1` and I have this feeling it can be done easily and in a very pythonic way, but half an hour of googling still make me think the easiest would be to make a dictionary with a mapping by hand (I only actually need it from 0 to 7).

```
Input    Intended output
b'\x00'  0 or '0'
b'\x01'  1 or '1'
```

etc.

Comment: What is your input and what is the intended output?

Comment: `b` means `bytes`, not binary. `\x00` is not string `0` but char with code `0` which can't be displayed so Python shows its code.

Comment: what result do you expect with `b"\x0F"` - `"F"` or `"15"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you want this result, but try it

```
output = [str(ord(x)) for x in output]
```

Comment: nice but there will be problem with `\x0F` and similar ;)

Comment: well... he said "I only actually need it from 0 to 7" :)

Answer (score 7):

A byte string is automatically a list of numbers.

```
input_bytes = b"\x00\x01"
output_numbers = list(input_bytes)
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you just looking for something like this?

```
for x in range(0,8):
    (x).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
```

Output is:

```
b'\x00'
b'\x01'
b'\x02'
b'\x03'
b'\x04'
b'\x05'
b'\x06'
b'\x07'
```

Or the reverse:

```
byteslist = [b'\x00',
b'\x01',
b'\x02',
b'\x03',
b'\x04',
b'\x05',
b'\x06',
b'\x07']

for x in byteslist:
    int.from_bytes(x,byteorder='big')
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wiil need to convert `b"\x0F"` into `F` then use

```
print( hex(ord(b'\x0F'))[2:] )
```

or with `format()`

```
print( format(ord(b'\x0F'), 'X') )    # '02X' gives string '0F'
print( '{:X}'.format(ord(b'\x0F')) )  # '{:02X}' gives string '0F'
```